# Parity through SOCKS5 Proxy?

Tags: parity

Is there a best practices method for running Parity through a SOCKS5 proxy?  Or should I try to figure one out.

This question was not considered long enough, so this is filler.  But I think I'm right that the above question was clear and complete I hope.